# Как создать систему с E2EE без MITM уязвимости?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, аутентификация, сертификат, цифровая-подпись

Если говорить про схему клиент-сервер, то клиент может проверить сертификат в СА, публичный ключ зашит в сертификате, поэтому левый публичный ключ он сможет распознать. Доменное имя тоже можно сверить с тем что в сертификате. В этой схеме клиенту важно следить за доменным именем.

Если рассмотреть систему мессенджера где происходит коммуникация клиент1-сервер-клиент2, то тут вроде нет доменного имени по которому необходимо сверять клиента с которым коммуницируешь. Тут вместо этого наверно стоит использовать номер телефона, который считаем известным заранее.

Из Википедии про E2EE:

> Для предотвращения MITM-атак большинство криптографических протоколов
> используют аутентификацию. Для этого могут использоваться, например,
> центры сертификации.

1. То есть все таки используют так же сертификаты СА, но без доменного имени, а с номером телефона к примеру? То есть СА дают возможность самим выбрать какие данные будут в сертификате?
2. Как такие сертификаты устанавливать браузерным/мобильным/десктопным клиентам при регистрации? Возможно ли это?
3. Запрос на генерацию в СА может происходить как на сервере так и на клиенте?
4. Как вообще видите архитектуру E2EE решения?

Если говорить о популярных мессенджерах, то при таких масштабах похоже что сертификаты должны быть бесплатными с авто генерацией новый при истечении срока действительности старых.

Из Википедии:

> Альтернативным методом является создание отпечатков открытого ключа на
> основе общедоступных открытых ключей пользователей или общих секретных
> ключей.

Кажется что такое возможно только если клиенты встречались для обмена открытыми/отпечатками откр.ключей/закрытыми ключами. А если есть возможность обмена ключами, то можно использовать обычную симметричную криптографию без всяких хитростей. Вроде такой подход не сложен в плане реализации и тут все понятно.

Comment: Сертификаты в E2E не используются по причине их бессмысленности. Пользователи сами проверяют друг друга, осуществляя ручную сверку ключей. Например, Telegram для этого отображает набор Emoji, сгенерированный из ключей шифрования — если смайлики у собеседников совпадают, значит MITM-атаки нет. Если же собеседники не обращают внимания на эти смайлики, то от MITM-атаки они не защищены.

Comment: Можно подробнее про эту схему? Откуда ключи шифрования на клиентах? Кто преобразовывает эти ключи  в Emoji, клиенты или сервер? Если секретные ключи выдает сервер Telegram, то он может все читать/шифровать(не E2EE). Если генерация Emoji на основе открытых ключей и используем асс. криптографию для обмена ключа шифрования между клиентами, то MITM возможна самим сервером Telegram. Если я не прав, пожалуйста, расскажите подробнее.

Comment: 1) Генерируются клиентами. 2) Клиенты. 3) Протокол Диффи-Хеллмана и прочие такие заумные математические штуки спасут от перехвата сгенерированных клиентами ключей.

Comment: Понял, похоже это преобразование публичных ключей в Emoji (отпечаток открытого ключа, то о чем было в Википедии). И я даже помню что такое было. Но сейчас специально зашел посмотреть, Telegram и WhatsApp теперь показывают текстовое значение отпечатка + кодированное изображение отпечатка, Viber ничего не показывает, а просто говорит что это E2EE. Следовательно для создания такой системы необходимо быть уверенным в надежности алгоритма создания отпечатков. Но минусы необходимости сверки пользователями остались.

Comment: А почему сертификаты бессмысленны? Пойму если вы скажете что есть проблемы их использования, но если бы можно было использовать, то польза - отсутствие необходимости сверки отпечатков открытого ключа .

Comment: Потому что сертификаты выдаются центрами сертификации, а доверие к центрам сертификации это само по себе одна гигантская уязвимость (нет гарантии, что центр сертификации не выдаст сертификат злоумышленнику, или что сам центр сертификации не является злоумышленником; подобные ситуации уже были на практике)

Comment: Теоретически, конечно, можно выпускать самоподписанные сертификаты или создать свой собственный маленький «центр сертификации», которому будут доверять только вы и ваши собеседники, но тогда всё равно где-то придётся в каком-то месте сверять отпечатки/смайлики вручную, так что смысла в этом мало